# Cloudflare permissions inconsistency

Tags: cloudflare

I created a cloudflare token and gave it "Zone -> Zone Settings -> Edit" permissions.

When I run `curl -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones" -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY-TOKEN>"` I see that the token has following permissions

```
"permissions": ["#zone_settings:read", "#zone_settings:edit", "#dns_records:read", "#dns_records:edit", "#page_shield:read", "#ssl:read", "#page_shield:edit", "#zone:edit", "#zone:read"],
```

This shows `"#dns_records:edit"` permission is present but when I try to create a DNS record I get error with message `Authentication error`.

When I explicitly give "Zone -> DNS -> Edit" permissions, I can create the DNS record.

Why does Cloudflare say that `"#dns_records:edit"` is present when only "Zone -> Zone Settings -> Edit" permission is given?

Comment: `https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones` shouldn't output token details at all. https://developers.cloudflare.com/api/operations/zones-get

Comment: The output does include the permissions I posted in the question